# How to use "UNION" in codeigniter query builder?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, union, query-builder

I am running a query with codeigniter query-builder :

```
   $this->db->select('t_heatpad.heatpad_status, 
          t_heatpad.idheatpad, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_firstname, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_lastname, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_address, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_phone, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_doc_firstname, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_doc_lastname, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_doc_npi, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_doc_phone, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_doc_fax, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_med_id, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_data_entered, 
          t_heatpad.heatpad_global ');
   $this->db->from('t_heatpad');
   $subQuery4 = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); 

    
   $this->db->select('t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_status, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.idcgmdiab, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_firstname, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_lastname, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_address, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_phone, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_doc_firstname, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_doc_lastname, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_doc_npi, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_doc_phone, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_doc_fax, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_medicare, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_date_entered, 
          t_cgm_diabetic.cgmdiab_global ');
  $this->db->from('t_cgm_diabetic');
  $subQuery5 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
```

Now I want to put union on $subQuery4 and $subQuery5 .
This method works fine for me :

```
$this->db->query("select * from ($subQuery4 UNION $subQuery5 ) as unionTable");
```

But I want to do that in this format:

```
 $this->db->select('*');    
 $this->db->from("($subQuery4 UNION $subQuery5 )");
 $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Please don't post code and error messages as an image but rather as code-formatted text since none of us can copy, paste and run an image. For more on this, 

please see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)
 
on SO when asking a question?. Also please check out the 
[**How to Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more on site best-practices.

Comment: Thanks for this information ....

Comment: np, but please place the error message as text in your question!